# Percorrer tags da resposta de um site C#

Tags: c#, http, async, response

Estou realizando uma consulta no google pelo C# e preciso pegar do retorno da consulta o Título da Consulta e o Link das consultas retornadas.

Obtive meu retorno da seguinte forma:

```
public class GoogleSearch
{
    private string _TituloPesquisa;
    private string _LinkPesquisa;
    private List<GoogleResultado> _GoogleResultadoList;

    static AutoResetEvent aguardarDocumentCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    public GoogleSearch()
    {
        _GoogleResultadoList = new List<GoogleResultado>();
    }

    public string GetResultJson 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _GoogleResultadoList.ToJsonSerialization<GoogleResultado>();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<GoogleResultado> GetListResults
    {
        get
        {
            return _GoogleResultadoList.ToList();
        }
    }

    public async Task Pesquisar(string textoConsulta)
    {
        await ExecuteSearchAsync(textoConsulta);
    }

    private async Task ExecuteSearchAsync(string textoConsulta)
    {
        string html = await GetHtmlResponse(textoConsulta);

        HtmlDocument documento = new HtmlDocument();
        documento.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlNodeCollection allElementsWithClassG = documento.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"g\"]");

        GoogleResultado resultado;
        HtmlNode link;
        foreach (HtmlNode x in allElementsWithClassG)
        {
            link = x.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
            resultado = new GoogleResultado();
            resultado.Titulo = link.InnerText;
            resultado.Url = link.Attributes["href"].Value.Replace("/url?q=", "");

            _GoogleResultadoList.Add(resultado);                
        }            
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetHtmlResponse(string textoConsulta)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com.br/search?num=100&q=" + textoConsulta);

        var streamRetorno = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
        return streamRetorno.ReadToEnd();             
    }                                           
}
```

> Chamada da execução:

```
    private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesquisa.Text))
            if (MessageBox.Show("Texto para pesquisa não informado.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                return;

        google.Pesquisar(txtPesquisa.Text);
        var stringJson = google.GetResultJson;
        var listresult = google.GetListResults;
    }
```

Tenho todos resultado da busca ai, mas como percorro as tags para obter as informações, alguém pode me ajudar?

> Retorno - essa é a string de retorno, mas ai esta só o começo, pois como é uma busca no google a string é bem grande.
>   [image: Retorno]

Comment: nun foi o que lhe passei ontem ?!

Comment: Como é o tipo de retorno?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, não deu certo porque ao usar o WebBrowser o Documento é gerado no evento assincrono, e eu preciso do resultado antes.

Comment: você pode continuar usando o namespace `System.Windows.Forms` ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, sim, posso, com aquela rotina deu tudo certo, só tive que descartar porque o evento do documentoCompleted é assincrono, e não consigo pausar o Navigate() e logo após trabalhar com o Document, ele demora pra carregar e quando carregado o método já foi executado, já tentei com Thread.Sleep Task.Delay nenhum obtive exito.

Comment: coloquei a resposta, vê se te ajuda

Comment: ainda sobre o WebBrowser, você pode colocar uma flag e um timeout pra esperar o documentCompleted, eu já fiz isso uma vez e funcionava de boa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar do `HtmlAgilityPack` que pode ser adicionado como referência no seu projeto pelo `Nuget`:

Feito isso, seguimos a mesma lógica do WebBrowser, só mudando algumas particularidades do componente:

Segue o código:

```
    private static async Task ExecuteSearchAsync(string textoConsulta)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com.br/search?num=100&q=" + textoConsulta);

        var streamRetorno = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
        string html =  streamRetorno.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection allElementsWithClassG = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"g\"]");

        List<Resultados> resultados = new List<Resultados>();
        Resultados r;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link;
        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode x in allElementsWithClassG)
        {
            link = x.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
            r = new Resultados();
            r.Titulo = link.InnerText;
            r.Url = link.Attributes["href"].Value.Replace("/url?q=", "");
            resultados.Add(r);
        }

        int cout = resultados.Count; //Sua List com todos os resultados da pesquisa.
    }


    public class Resultados
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: O Sistema para nesse trecho. HtmlDocument doc = new WebBrowser().Document.OpenNew(true);

Comment: ok, testando...

Comment: editado, acho que vai funcionar =] e você ainda pode descartar o `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: @Ronovann, estou tentando instalar o HtmlAgilityPack e está dando esse erro. 'HtmlAgilityPack' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Net.Http'. (Eu já referenciei no projeto a DLL system.net.http)

Comment: Instalei o cloudscribe.HtmlAgilityPack e deu certo meu amigo, cara, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajudo, você é fera!!!

Comment: Ronovann, ainda estou com problema nessa situação de Async, vou editar e colocar como estou fazendo a chamada dessa API, vê se pode me ajudar, pois quando estou pegando as propriedades que tenho os resultados, os mesmo ainda vem nulo, pois esse metodo de pesquisar está rodando em outra Thread Ainda.

Comment: Não teria que usar o await na chamada do pesquisar?

Comment: Resolvido: private async void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPesquisa.Text))
                if (MessageBox.Show("Texto para pesquisa não informado.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    return;

            await google.Pesquisar(txtPesquisa.Text);
            var stringJson = google.GetResultJson;
            var listresult = google.GetListResults;
        }

Comment: maravilha, parabens